# Loading AJAX calls one after the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following 3 AJAX function, and the problem is that it loads sessionAllCoursePage3 first then sessionAllCoursePage2 then sessionAllCoursePage1, I wanted to be inverse. I want to ensure that page1 is loaded first, then page 2, page 3, etc.

```
// Retrieve last 9 session
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { run: true, providerName: $('#providerName').val() },
    url: '/app/functions/sessionAllCoursePage1.php',
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        // Response is value returned from php
        $('#contentPage1').html(response);
        return false;
    }
});

// Retrieve the next 9 session

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { run: true, providerName: $('#providerName').val() },
    url: '/app/functions/sessionAllCoursePage2.php',
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        // Response is value returned from php
        $('#contentPage2').html(response);
        return false;
    }
});

// Retrieve the next 9 session

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { run: true, providerName: $('#providerName').val() },
    url: '/app/functions/sessionAllCoursePage3.php',
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        // Response is value returned from php
        $('#contentPage3').html(response);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Start the second ajax function from the success handler in the first.  Then start the third ajax function from the success handler of the second.  This will guarantee the sequencing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am a bit new to this, and could you a little assistance

Comment: Why do you want them to run one after the other? As they are now the browser can run them simultaneously.

Comment: @John - I did.  I provided three different code solutions in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you chain them with promises:

```
// Retrieve last 9 session
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        run: true,
        providerName: $('#providerName').val()
    },
    url: '/app/functions/sessionAllCoursePage1.php',
    cache: false
}).then(function(response) {

    $('#contentPage1').html(response);

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            run: true,
            providerName: $('#providerName').val()
        },
        url: '/app/functions/sessionAllCoursePage2.php',
        cache: false
}).then(function(response) {

    $('#contentPage2').html(response);

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            run: true,
            providerName: $('#providerName').val()
        },
        url: '/app/functions/sessionAllCoursePage3.php',
        cache: false
    });    
}).then(function(response) {
    $('#contentPage3').html(response);
});
```

---

Or, using a little more shared code:

```
function ajaxCommon(url, resultId) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: url, 
        data: {
            run: true,
            providerName: $('#providerName').val()
        },
        cache: false
    }).then(function(result) {
        $("#" + resultId).html(result);
    });
}

ajaxCommon('/app/functions/sessionAllCoursePage1.php', 'contentPage1').then(function() {
    return ajaxCommon('/app/functions/sessionAllCoursePage2.php', 'contentPage2');
}).then(function() {
    return ajaxCommon('/app/functions/sessionAllCoursePage3.php', 'contentPage3');
});
```

---

Or, a little more table/loop driven:

```
function ajaxCommon(url, resultId) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: url, 
        data: {run: true, providerName: $('#providerName').val()},
        cache: false
    }).then(function(result) {
        $("#" + resultId).html(result);
    });
}

[1,2,3].reduce(function(p, item) {
    return p.then(function() {
        return ajaxCommon('/app/functions/sessionAllCoursePage' + item + '.php', 'contentPage' + item);
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.shift()`, `String.prototype.match()` with `Regexp` `/\d/` to match digit character in `url`, `.then()`

```
    function request(url) {
      return $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              data: {run: true, providerName: $('#providerName').val()},
              url: url,
              cache:false,
              success: function (response) {
                $('#contentPage' + url.match(/\d/)[0]).html(response);
              }
            });
    }

    var urls = ['/app/functions/sessionAllCoursePage1.php'
               , '/app/functions/sessionAllCoursePage2.php'
               , '/app/functions/sessionAllCoursePage3.php'];

    request(urls.shift())
    .then(function re() {
      if (urls.length) {
        request(urls.shift()).then(re)
      }
    })
    // can use `.catch()` here at jQuery 3.0+
    .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // handle error
      console.log(errorThrown);
    });
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/fREO6Jzw65gq2s3jrwjp?p=preview

Comment: Yes, will update. Overall approach should return expected result

Comment: Slick idea using shift though

Comment: @charlietfl See updated post, substituted using two `.then()` calls, recursion for multiple `.then()`

Comment: I'm not used to naming a function while creating a callback like that. Interesting way to re-use it

Answer (score 1):

Just place your asynchronous code inside some request callback (e.g. success). Didactically:

```
var firstRequestOptions = {
  success: function () {
    secondRequest(); 
  }
};
var secondRequestOptions = {
  success: function () {
    thirdRequest(); 
  }
};
var thirdRequestOptions = {
  success: function () {
    firstRequest(); 
  }
};
var firstRequest = function () {
  console.log('request 1'); 
  $.ajax(firstRequestOptions); 
};
var secondRequest = function () { 
  console.log('request 2'); 
  $.ajax(secondRequestOptions);
};
var thirdRequest = function () { 
  console.log('request 3'); 
  $.ajax(thirdRequestOptions); 
};
```

Then:

```
firstRequest();
```

The log should be:

```
> request 1
> request 2
> request 3
> request 1
> request 2
...
```